# RouterModule.forRoot() called twice again

Tags: angular, typescript

I've looked over some of the answers on the other post but I don't see where I'm going wrong here.

I have a button that on click is going to /npo/join. I have 2 lazy loaded modules and one app module. I believe I'm calling forChild appropriately and not accidently importing AppRoutingModule into any lazy loaded module, so I'm not sure how it's getting called twice on this button click.

AppRoutingModule looks like this:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginComponent } from './shared/login/login.component';
import { RegisterComponent } from './shared/register/register.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '',  loadChildren: () => import('./home/home.module').then(m => m.HomeModule)},
  { path: 'npo', loadChildren: () => import('./npo/npo.module').then(m => m.NPOModule)},
  { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

App.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA  } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NavMenuComponent } from './nav-menu/nav-menu.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { NgxSpinnerModule } from "ngx-spinner";
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { NPOModule } from './npo/npo.module';
import { SharedModule } from './shared/shared.module';
import { HomeModule } from './home/home.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavMenuComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    HomeModule,
    SharedModule,
    NPOModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: 'ng-cli-universal' }),
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    NgxSpinnerModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  exports: [],
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

NPORoutingModule:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { NpoDashboardComponent } from './dashboard/npo-dashboard.component';
import { NpoNewComponent } from './npo-new/npo-new.component';


const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'join', component: NpoNewComponent },
  { path: 'dashboard/:id', component: NpoDashboardComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class NPORoutingModule { }
```

NPO Module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NpoComponent } from './npo/npo.component';
import { NpoNewComponent } from './npo-new/npo-new.component';
import { TabsModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/tabs';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { SharedModule } from '../shared/shared.module';
import { NpoDashboardComponent } from './dashboard/npo-dashboard.component';
import { NPORoutingModule } from './npo-routing.module';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    NpoComponent,
    NpoNewComponent,
    NpoDashboardComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    NPORoutingModule,
    SharedModule,
    CommonModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    FormsModule,
    TabsModule.forRoot()
  ],
  providers: [],
  schemas: []
})
export class NPOModule { }
```

HomeRouting.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './home.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
]

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class HomeRoutingModule { }
```

Home module.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { HomeRoutingModule } from './home-routing.module';
import { HomeComponent } from './home.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [HomeComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    HomeRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: []
})
export class HomeModule { }
```

Comment: You are importing `NPOModule` inside of `AppModule`. Remove that import and you should be good to go.

Comment: That didn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: I removed HomeModule from App.Module.ts imports too. I get the error in console on app load now.

Comment: All lazy loaded modules should ONLY be referenced through the `loadChildren`-syntax. No manual import is allowed anywhere else. What error do you receive when you removed all direct imports of all lazy-loaded modules in AppModule (and only keep the reference through AppRoutingModule)?